# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview

I have the below sub which checks all of a node's child nodes in a Windows form treeview when the node is checked. I get the error stated in the subject whenever I click it, but this only happens when settings the checked property. If I just run the commented out MsgBox line, it works fine with no errors.

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterCheck(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As _
    TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterCheck
    For Each s As TreeNode In TreeView1.Nodes
        If s.Checked = True Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To s.Nodes.Count - 1
                MsgBox(s.Nodes(i).Text)
                s.Nodes(i).Checked = True
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

As it is a StackOverflow Exception, this seemed like the best place to ask about it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Documentation for the TreeView.AfterCheck event says:

> Setting the `TreeNode.Checked`
>   property from within a `BeforeCheck`
>   or `AfterCheck` event handler causes
>   the event to be raised multiple times
>   and can result in unexpected behavior.
>   To prevent the event from being raised
>   multiple times, add logic to your
>   event handler that only executes your
>   recursive code if the `Action`
>   property of the `TreeViewEventArgs` is
>   not set to `TreeViewAction.Unknown`.

The event is being raised every time you call s.Nodes(i).Checked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jim. I've used a combination of yours and Patrick McDonald's answers as my final solution. Code is in the comment of Patrick's post.

Answer (score 8):

What's happening is that within the AfterCheck event you're 'Checking' a tree node, which fires the AfterCheck event, in which you 'Check' a node, which fires the AfterCheck event, in which you 'Check' a node, which fires the AfterCheck event, in which you 'Check' a node, which fires the AfterCheck event, in which you 'Check' a node, which fires the AfterCheck event, in which you 'Check' a node, which fires the AfterCheck event, in which you 'Check' a node, which fires the AfterCheck event, in which you 'Check' a node, which fires the AfterCheck event, in which you 'Check' a node, which fires the AfterCheck event, in which you 'Check' a node, which fires the AfterCheck event, in which you 'Check' a node, which fires the AfterCheck event, in which you 'Check' a node, which fires the AfterCheck event, in which you 'Check' a node, which fires the AfterCheck event, in which you 'Check' a node, which causes the stack overflow.

To fix, don't set Checked in an AfterCheck event handler.

Comment: Funny and clear illustration of the problem. Could have used some formatting though ;o)

Comment: I feel a bit silly now that I didn't realise that earlier. Very funny illustration of the problem though :)

Comment: The final advice is not wrong; a bit incomplete, yes, but not wrong.  The final advice would definitely fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
s.Nodes(i).Checked = True
```

causes the event `TreeView1_AfterCheck` to be triggered itself. So it's an infinite loop.

You need to rewrite the code more carefully, so that you don't re-assign `Checked = True` if `Checked` is already true, and perhaps use a private field to check to see if the current event is already running upon entry.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating through all the root nodes of the TreeView, you can simply iterate through the child nodes of the checked node that raised the event:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterCheck(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterCheck
    If e.Node.Checked Then
        For Each child As TreeNode In e.Node.Nodes
            child.Checked = True
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

You don't need to check for e.Action here, and indeed should not, for 2 reasons:

- As you are enumerating the children of the checked node then you will not have a problem with infinite recursion you were having in your original code.
- If you exit when e.Action = unknown, then if you have 3 levels in your treeview, it will only select the immediate children of the node you selected, and not all descendants.

Comment: Thanks Patrick.
 Below is the code I settled on using:

        If e.Action <> TreeViewAction.Unknown Then
            For Each child As TreeNode In e.Node.Nodes
                child.Checked = e.Node.Checked
            Next
        End If

This way it automatically works to uncheck all the child nodes as well.

Now how do I close a question on this website?

Comment: Never mind, found it. Who would've though it'd be that extremely obvious big fat tick on the page! :)